# Reading EOF with getline(std::cin, variable) - C++

Tags: c++, string, queue, getline, eof

The EOF doesn't work. Please help. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line; // string
    queue<string> a; // queue for output
    while (getline(cin, line) && !cin.eof())
    { // EOF working?
        for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
            if (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] % 2 == 0)
                line[i] -= 32;
        a.push(line);
    }
    while (!a.empty())
    {
        cout << a.front() << endl;
        a.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I do "while(getline(cin, line))" ?

Comment: Because if `getline()` encounters an end of file condition, it sets the stream to a failed state, and in the boolean context it will evaluate to `false`. `cin.eof()` will never be checked.

Comment: On the upside, if `getline(cin,line)` fails, you exit anyway. You don't need it. You must have some other bug if you even noticed `!cin.eof()` wasn't working. For example, `cin` doesn't have an eof unless you close the input stream. `getline` will sit waiting for the user to keep typing for eternity if nothing else happens. Try ctrl + z or ctrl + d. One's Windows, the other Linux. Can't remember which.

Comment: "*The EOF doesn't work*" isn't a useful problem description. What, precisely, is the input to your program? What, precisely, is the result? What is your expected result? See [ask] and [mcve] for more information.

Comment: If STDIN has been redirected to an input file, for instance, then `EOF` makes sense, but `std::getline()` would still handle that condition anyway.  So it is still not necessary to check `!cin.eof()` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `while(getline(cin, line))` in fact the `&& !cin.eof()` does nothing, as pointed out by *Sam Varshavchik*, because `getline` does all the work and exits the while loop by setting the stream to a failed state on it's own, therefore, `cin.eof` is never dealt with.

> The extraction also stops if the end of file is reached in [the input stream] or if some other error occurs during the input operation.

This is stated in the documentation at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)